# Why "if" works but "switch" doesn't work?

Tags: javascript

```
// It is simple code

var num = prompt("put number");
// This way is not worked 
switch (num) {
    case num > 0:
        console.log("num++");
        break;
    case num < 0:
        console.log(num-2);
        break;
}
// But this worked
if (num > 0){
    console.log(num++);
} else if (num < 0){
    console.log(num -2);
}
```

My first way by "switch" is not worked but "if" method worked.

I tried all of thing for changing code or other ways but the same result.

Please guys help me.

Comment: in 'case' you don't perform logic you just specify what the case needs to be.  Given a list of num you can specify a case for each num and perform logic accordingly.

Comment: That's not the way a `switch` statement works. The value of `num` will be compared to the values of the `case` expressions. Why do you need it to be a `switch` anyway? There's nothing wrong with the `if` version of the code.

Comment: Becouse I want learn both ways bu thank you for your help bro

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because the statement `num > 0` inside you `case` will return `true` or `false`.
If you do this:

```
switch (true) {
    case num > 0:
        console.log("num++");
        break;
    case num < 0:
        console.log(num-2);
        break;
}
```

It will work.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Cases cannot be expressions, you must normalize your input first.</strike>

Although it is valid to place an expression in a `case`, in this scenario a more tried-and-true way of dealing with this is to first normalize your input first.

You can determine direction for example:

```js
var num = parseInt(prompt("put number"), 10);
var direction = num < 0 ? -1 : 1;

switch (direction) {
    case 1:
        console.log("num++");
        break;
    case -1:
        console.log(num - 2);
        break;
}
```

Comment: "Cases cannot be expressions" - not true.

Comment: @georg After looking into the documentation, it appears that you can validate an expression against the switch... But this seems like a hack, because it seems to act as an inverse switch. In that case, a traditional if-else would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

The switch acts as a case switcher, meaning you cannot make comparisons to create cases, just list cases by case, and perform some function from this case. The if / else structure is suitable for making comparisons, as the expected result in the if call is always a boolean.

Example:

```
const a = 1;

if (a === 1) {
    console.log('hello');
} else {
    console.log('sad');

switch (a) {
    case 1 : console.log('hello'); break;
    default: console.log('sad'); break;
```

In your case, I recommend using if/else if/else, as it is more recommended.